# What exactly does "Posts page" do in WordPress?

Tags: php, html, templates

Hay, I'm making a WordPress template, and i have 4 main pages.

```
HOME
BLOG
CONTACT
ABOUT US
```

As you can see "Blog" is a page (i need it to display when i call wp_list_pages()), but how do i edit this blog page? I assigned the "Blog" page a custom temeplate (called blog.php), but when "Blog" is set as the "Post page" in the Reading section of the WordPress admin, the page fails to render the template.

How do i edit this "Blog" page?

Comment: for http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: Does it work as normal page? Btw: show us your code and tell us what exactly you tried so far.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Setting page to be "posts page" changes its template hierarchy to follow [home page rules](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Home_Page_display).

So your custom template is ignored and it looks for `home.php` or `index.php`, which might or might not be the reason it fails to render.

Comment: So home.php is the blog page, and index.php is the home page. Is this documented anywhere?

Comment: @dotty not quite, `home.php` is home page with list of latest posts and `index.php` is fallback template for everything that doesn't have more specific template. See [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) in Codex.

Answer (score 1):

When you set a page to be the Posts Page, it will override any custom template or content you assign and automatically use `index.php` to render the posts loop.

Comment: Actually, at least if the site is set to use a static Page as the Front Page, then whatever static Page is assigned for the blog posts index will use *home.php*.